# How to get Salesforce upsertResults count in OnComplete phase in Batch component on Mule

Tags: salesforce, mule, batch-processing

In the mule flow, I have iterated upsertResults and add it into arraylist in the process phase, but sometimes its not showing exact result because its based on batch size it keep on changing I think. And also I couldn't access flowvars in Oncomplete phase. Hereby I added my mule configuration code,

```html
<batch:job name="Student-Application-Upsert-Batch" max-failed-records="-1">
    <batch:threading-profile poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
    <batch:input>
        <data-mapper:transform doc:name="CSV To List&lt;Account&gt;" config-ref="CSV_To_List_Account_" stream="true"/>
    </batch:input>
    <batch:process-records>
        <batch:step name="Upsert-Account">
            <batch:commit  doc:name="Batch Commit" streaming="true">
                <sfdc:upsert config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_authentication" externalIdFieldName="Email_Address_Key__c" type="Account" doc:name="Upsert Account">
                    <sfdc:objects ref="#[payload]"/>
                </sfdc:upsert>
                <foreach   doc:name="For Each Result Record" >
                    <choice doc:name="Choice">
                        <when expression="#[payload.success == 'true']">
                            <set-variable variableName="Success" value="#[SuccessResult.add(message.payload)]" doc:name="Success Records"/>
                        </when>
                        <otherwise>
                            <set-variable variableName="Failure" value="#[FailureResult.add(message.payload)]" doc:name="Failure Records"/>
                        </otherwise>
                    </choice>
                </foreach>
                <logger message="#####-------------&gt;Failures: #[flowVars.FailureResult.size()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Log Failure Records"/>
                <logger message="#####-------------&gt;Success: #[flowVars.SuccessResult.size()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Log Success Records"/>
                <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="${MULE.PROCESSED_FILES}" outputPattern="#[flowVars.UpsertLogName]" connector-ref="LogFileWritter" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Upsert Results Log File"/>
            </batch:commit>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step name="Log-Failures" accept-policy="ONLY_FAILURES">
            <logger message="Record with the following payload has failed. Payload:: #[message.payload], Loading Phase: #[failureExceptionForStep], Inside Failure the exception is :- #[getStepExceptions()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Log Failure"/>
            <!-- <foreach collection="#[payload]" doc:name="For Each">
                <logger message="For earch resultset row Payload is #[message.payload], counter is #[flowVars['counter']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </foreach>-->
            <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="${MULE.FAILURE_LOGS}" outputPattern="OnlyFailures_#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename].txt"  responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="LogFileWritter"/>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:process-records>
    <batch:on-complete>
        <logger message="Batch Failed Records: #[payload.failedRecords]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <logger message="#####-------------&gt;Failures: #[flowVars.FailureResult.size()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Failure Size Logger"/>
        <logger message="Number of failed Records: #[payload.failedRecords] " level="INFO" doc:name="Failed Records" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message=" Number of loadedRecord: #[payload.loadedRecords]"/>
         <logger message="Number of successful Records: #[flowVars.SuccessResult.size()]"    level="INFO" doc:name="Successful Records" />
         <logger message="ElapsedTime #[payload.getElapsedTimeInMillis()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Elapsed Time" />
     </batch:on-complete>
</batch:job>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see flowVars in the on complete but the actions you toke over them inside the steps will probably not get propagated as inside each step you're working with a copy of the message. FYI record vars won't do either as you can't see them in the on complete.

I think the best option you have here is to use object store or custom code like a java bean to store the values you want to access in on complete. Be careful with concurrency as the writing of that value in the last step can be potentially run by several threads and it's up to you to synchronise them (Object store won't help you with that either I think) .

HTH.